# Shiny applications in Microsoft R Server

Tags: r, azure, shiny, microsoft-r

Does Microsoft R Server facilitates R shiny applications?

I found that in Azure we can set up a Microsoft R server, so can this be used to host shiny applications as well?

Comment: Why not, it is a debian package, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run shiny apps on Microsoft Azure. See instructions for dockerizing a shiny app [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/dockerizing-a-shiny-app/).